# Is their any ways to solve the inconsistency of the mapping error in ODI12C?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-data-integrator

I am very new to ODI12C. I am having issue with the mapping(java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number). the error is intermittent I figure out the solution but, it won't work every time.

**Issue **
I want to change date to number using expression component which shows "Error Msg = ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE" to solve this I used aggregate component to count the date and pass number value, which solve the issue but, when I execute it, it only works one time or two times then I receive "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number" when ever I change something like LKM randomly it will work for another one or two times.

Any idea what is the issue could be?

I try to change LKM randomly which help me to execute one or two times successfully.
I am expecting the mapping to work at all times once it work